# How can I swap seperated ":" columns in sed?

Tags: sed

How can I swap columns seperated ":" using sed?

for example

```
string1:string2


string3 string4:string5


string6:string7-string8
```

into

```
string2:string1

string5:string3 string4

string7-string8:string6
```

thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: sed -E 's/([^:]+):(.*)/\2:\1/' that's what I tried and I have 
sed e expression #1, char 21: unterminated 's' command

Comment: `cat inputfile|sed -E 's/([^:]+):(.*)/\2:\1/' ` produced exactly the desired output as per your example.. no `sed` errors on my end

Comment: Please add all attempts to your question by editing it

Comment: Keep in mind that you don't use `sed` standalone, you have a shell in between that might be interpreting some characters in special ways. You won't find those documented in `sed`'s manpage and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

This code will swap the columns around `:` in a file named `example.txt` -

```
sed -i -r 's/(.+):(.+)/\2:\1/' example.txt
```

Explanation -

- `-i` is for in-place substitution
- `-r` forces `sed` to use an extended regular syntax
- `.+` says look for any character any number of times. This is a very "greedy" regular expression but works in this case. Then, parentheses are used to capture the text.
- Then, finally used `\1` and `\2` in reverse order to swap the columns around `:`